# Split one large xml file into multiple small files by keyword

Tags: java, xml

I want to split a large xml file into many small xml files by keyword (R17:25:37.267 or S17:23:46.470), by reading XML data using XPath in Java. How can this be accomplished in Java?
Thanks!

```
[S17:23:46.470][  DE01][00037620000000000000000<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GB18030"?>
<ROOT>
  <HEAD>
    <VERSION/>
    <MSG_TYPE>2</MSG_TYPE>
     .............
    <RET_MSG/>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <REQUEST>
      <IDE_INFO>
        ......................
      </IDE_INFO>
      <IDE_INFO>
        .....................
      </IDE_INFO>
      <IDE_INFO>
       ......................
      <IDE_INFO>
        ....................
      </IDE_INFO>
      </IDE_ACC>
    </RESPONSE>
  </BODY>
</ROOT>]

[R17:25:37.267][  DE01][0002882BA207D8F5E8E6C9F<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK" ?><ROOT>
  <HEAD>
    <VERSION></VERSION>
    <TERM_NO>000</TERM_NO>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <REQUEST>
      .................................
      <IDE_INFOCOUNT>00000015</IDE_INFOCOUNT>
      <IDE_INFOCount>15</IDE_INFOCount>
      <IDE_INFO>
        ...............................
      </WITHDRAW_DETAIL>
    </REQUEST>
  </BODY>
</ROOT>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input you have shown us is not an XML file as described in your title and question, it is a file containing chunks of text interspersed with chunks of XML. If that's your actual input, then you're going to have to write some kind of parser yourself, because an XML parser won't handle non-XML input.

If you're lucky then the character string `<?xml...?>` only appears at the start of an XML chunk, so recognising it in a simple Java program shouldn't be too difficult.

A better idea though: XML is a good standard for data interchange. Why not persuade whoever generated this stuff to use XML instead? It would make everyone's life much easier.